# How can I migrate a local bitnami stack to digitalocean

Tags: stack, cloud, digital-ocean, migrate, bitnami

I have moved to a country with very slow internet and therefore I can no longer play with cloud based servers easily

I therefore want to work on a locally hosted bitnami stack and  when I am happy go to one of the only places in town with reliable internet and upload my completed website to digitalocean.

Can anybody give me some simple guidance on how to do this?
Are there better alternatives?

Many thanks for your support